# Trying to use an accurate reference (GIS/Google map) to help create a Stylized NPR (comic/cartoon) background/midground for an animation

Tags: materials, sculpting, texture-painting, shader-nodes, layers

I'm relatively new at Blender and trying to make an animation with a specific location in mind. I have the addon BlenderGIS to help me generate the area for my scenes, but not sure how to go about using the addon as a reference to go back and forth from. I want to repaint/shade the area to be used as my background/midground but haven't figured out if I should try something like texture painting or sculpture painting. I was having issues using original and duplicated meshes since changing materials on one would affect both objects. Maybe there is a way to use layers here or could I be overlooking something? I was also looking into sculpture painting, but again, I didn't see a way to keep using the original GIS/Google height map as a reference. I tried using node combinations- to no avail (results were not what I was looking for-such as with the use of toon shading). Any Ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Sorry, meant to reply back but lost track during the holidays. Currently working on other areas of the animation. I didn't know of a way to stylize GIS map data and plan on culling or chopping out a lot of those unused vertices when I get back to the background. Will try to post an image or repost a question with the image in the near future.